# misalignment warnings fix them or no?

Tags: c++, memory-alignment, type-punning

in my custom `.zip` decompressor I get warnings like these:

```
runtime error: load of misaligned address 0x7f280ffe875a for type 'const uint32_t', which requires 4 byte alignment
```

The reason is a `reinterpret_cast` to `uint32_t*` and dereferencing of the same. I know that `memcpy` into an `uint32_t` would fix the problem, but should I bother? I see the same kind of warnings with many widely-used libraries (like pixman, cairo, ...).

Comment: Depends on the CPU architecture on x86 you can most likely get away with it.  On ARM it will probably hardware trap.  However you are in Undefined Behaviour territory and the compiler is allowed to assume that you are not doing UB so anything can happen.

Comment: But pixman might be used in arm country too.

Comment: I think UB trumps all discussions of CPU architecture.  I only have it as my 2nd point because the above was just a quick comment.

Comment: @user1095108: "*But pixman might be used in arm country too.*" And if someone tries, it'll blow up in ARM country. Unaligned reads are not something you can just ignore.

Comment: @NicolBolas There's always the manual armv6+ support unaligned reads. Pixman is used by cairo and it contains optimized code for each platform it supports. I think it knows it can afford to break the rules on x86, as different code is compiled/linked in for arm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always fix them. The vectorizer of your compiler may use the alignment info and it assumes that you do not invoke undefined behavior. This can lead to crashes.

See: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65709 for a discussion of this issue between gcc devs and the author of LZ4.